# Add member counter to bot activity discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to do that but it isn't working. How can I resolve this?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity(`[${member.guild.memberCount}] Players`, {type: "PLAYING"});
});
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    client.user.setActivity(`[${member.guild.memberCount}] Players`, {type: "PLAYING"});
});
client.on("guildMemberRemove", member => {
    client.user.setActivity(`[${member.guild.memberCount}] Players`, {type: "PLAYING"});
});
```

Comment: what version of discord.js are you using? and what do you mean by it isn't working? do you mean it's not updating or do you mean it's not showing anything?

Comment: I'm using discord.js version 12

Comment: And when I run the bot, it doesn't show the bot activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map clients guilds, to get membersCount value and then get summ of members with reduce method.

This code will update members count every 1 min.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const token = require('./token.json').token
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        let membersCount = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.memberCount).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
        client.user.setActivity(`[${membersCount}] Players`, {type: "PLAYING"});
    }, 1000 * 60);

});

client.login(token)
```